# delphi QRPDFDocumentFilter generate protected pdf file

Tags: delphi, pdf

I'm using QRPDFDocumentFilter to generate pdf file with this

```
 try
    lPdfFilter := TQRPDFDocumentFilter.Create(nomefile);
    TQuickRep(MainForm.QRPreview1.QRPrinter.ParentReport).ExportToFilter(lPdfFilter);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(lPDFFilter);
  end;
```

but is possible to create a protected file?
My goal is create a file impossible to modify (protected)
thanks for help

Comment: No, the QRPDFDocumentFilter does not support encrypted/protected files. It's strictly a quick-export filter.